# Screen Resolution is just in 640x480?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, monitor

i tried to change it in displays but the result is unknown and there is no drop down arrow. what should i do?

Comment: Try this: connect to the internet first, then open the system settings > hardware drivers. Are there any display drivers to activate? If yes, do it, then ok!

Comment: @B.Roland Write it as an answer Please

Comment: Done. @user38236 may accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Connect to the internet, then open the System > Settings > Hardware drivers. Or in Unity Dash > Hardware Drivers.

[image: Hardware Drivers window]

Are there any display drivers to activate? If yes, activate it!

I hope it helps.